# Play WS (2.2.1): post/put large request

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play.WS to issue http requests. My goal is to send a put request with a large file.

```
val requestHolder = WS.url("http://" + host)
requestHolder.put(???)
```

I don't know what should be the type of ??? to stream the body. The requestHolder has a put(File file) method - which I can't use because I don't have the file - and put[T](T body) where T can be anything as long as you have an instance of Writable[T].

There are some default writables defined for json, text, xml, etc. But non for an InputStream for example.

The documentation gives a (brief) hint to handle large *responses* but nothing about large *requests* (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS)

Anyone knows how to define a writable that would accept an InputStream? Or maybe an Iteratee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WS underlying client takes `InputStream`](http://sonatype.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/reference/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder.html). Access it like this:

```
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient

val client:AsyncHttpClient = WS.client
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported yet.

There is a little discussion about it here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1510

And we're hoping that for Play 2.3, we will have a solution to allow it.